# Arithmetic overflow - handling overflown cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal, overflow

I failed to fix this case even after looking to many threads.

I have a column of decimal(8,4) and a data table containing 4 cases, which are way of line and exceed upper limit. That's fine. I have an import script, where performance is no issue, it will be used max ~20 times.

I tried to handle the problem many ways, like (this code is part of SELECT statement):

```
CASE WHEN PRT.InputColumn > 999 THEN 999.9999 ELSE PRT.InputColumn END as MyColumn
```

But apparently, the server thinks in decimal(8,4) when evaluating the WHEN statement and throws error anyway. OK, I thought this might resolve the problem:

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(12,4), PRT.InputColumn) IS NULL THEN 999.9999 ELSE PRT.InputColumn END as MyColumn
```

But still, I get the same error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

So I mean to keep the columnd datatype as is and handle the excessive values. What would be the correct way to **handle the overflown values**?

Comment: It should be `TRY_CONVERT(decimal(8,4))` instead of `12,4`. And if it's `decimal(8,4)` it can be up to 9999 instead of 999. Shorter syntax:  `COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(8,4)), 9999.9999)`

Comment: I've started with decimal(8,4) but that wouldn't allow for the excessive numbers, so I tried to scale it up; now that you pointed that out, I see this doesn't make sense with comparison to NULL. I've had there 9999, just tried to lower the bound for safety when it wasn't working. The shorter syntax make sense; you're missing the input variable, but I get the point :-). I'll repeat couple of testing, to make sure I didn't miss the correct syntax. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @dnoteth: Oh, shame on me. When attemting to test around, I did miss the correct combination of syntax... Both of your suggestion works. If you copy&paste it to a separate answer, I'd be pleased to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you TRY_CONVERT to a DECIMAL(12,4) you might get larger values than 9999, of course they fail to fit into a DECIMAL(8,4).

Simply switch to 8,4 instead:

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(8,4), PRT.InputColumn) IS NULL 
     THEN 9999.9999 
     ELSE PRT.InputColumn
END as MyColumn
```

or shorter:

```
COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(8,4), PRT.InputColumn), 9999.9999)
```

Caution, both will convert large *negative*  values to `9999.9999`, too.